# gcc object file linking

Tags: c, gcc, linker

I'm learning C by rehashing some Project Euler problems, as I did for Python. In Python, I created a file of general mathematical utilities such as prime number checking, which I pulled functions out of as and when I needed them. I was wondering if there was a way to simply do a similar thing with C, other than compiling alongside the utilities file each time?

I'm running Linux and using gcc as my compiler, if that helps.

Comment: In C, you create modules (usually each a collection of functions and/or static variables in a file, say `module_x.c`), then you compile and link them with your main program. That's oversimplifying a bit, but probably good for your case. In more complex cases, you might build a library (`.so` or `.a`) and have programs that require it link to it when they're built. You also want header files `.h` which files include to define the interface to the modules. I'm covering a lot of ground in just a few sentences. So you might want to Google "C modules and libraries" or something like that.

Comment: With the Project Euler programs I'll be creating there will be one source file for each problem, what would be the most efficient way of linking these files?

Comment: Do you mean that the different "problems" access the same set of libraries (core functions) you want to create?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you need some basic knowledge about separate compilation and libraries(archives and shared libraries). You can read about it in chapter "2.3 Writing and Using Libraries" of

- [Advanced Linux Programming, 1st Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735710430) by CodeSourcery LLC, Mark L. Mitchell, Alex Samuel, Jeffrey Oldham.

This book is also available as a PDF from http://www.advancedlinuxprogramming.com/ (although the site is down at the moment). Perhaps you can search for other places to legally download the PDF.

A crash course:

- You create a number of object (`*.o`) files  via

  ```
  gcc name.c -o name.o
  ```
- Each file has a header that declares the functions in the source file.  You might have several source files using a single header if the functions are related.  The source files such as `name.c` include that header.  Your code that uses those functions also includes that header.
- You create a static library (archive) with `ar`

  ```
  ar ruv libXYZ.a name1.o name2.o ... nameN.o
  ```

  The prefix `lib` is important.
- You link to the library with

  ```
  gcc prog.o -lXYZ -o prog
  ```

  This command will create an executable named `prog` from the object file `prog.o` and from object files, extracted from `libXYZ.a`, which are required to satisfy symbol references from `prog.o`.

Comment: This looks like what I want. For the final step of linking the library could it be run as `gcc prog.c -lXYZ -o prog`?